# Migration Error On Passing connection string to code-first DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have a DBContext driven class named OnlineShoppingContext like below:

```
public class OnlineShoppingContext:DbContext
{
    public OnlineShoppingContext(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I use it in following code:

```
using (var context = new OnlineShoppingContext("ConnectionStringValue"))
{
    if (context.Users.Any(item => item.Email == Email && item.Password == "pass"))
        session["Username"] = Email;
}
```

But I receive following exception:

```
The model backing the 'OnlineShoppingContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

I recreate database using Delete and then CreateIfDoesNotExist method of dbcontext but again i receive mentioned exception. What I must to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "I recreate database using CreateIfDoesNotExist method of dbcontext"? Have you deleted the database and recreated it? The method CreateIfDoesNotExist, as it read, seems to create the database if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes I delete database first using context.Database.Delete()

Comment: Do you use EF initaliser? for example:
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>());

Comment: Which database are you using? Can you just manually delete the DB, just to make sure EF will recreate it? The error you are getting is a "default" one when your model doesn't match your database. (EF code-first)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I delete database manually but error reminded.

Comment: I must tell that I created database using a unit test project and using it on another project that is ASP MVC 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have set a DB Initializer, try using the following:

```
Database.SetInitializer<OnlineShoppingContext>(null);
```